# Seralizing a keras model with an embedding layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, word-embedding

I've trained a model with pre-trained word embeddings like this:

```
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, 100))
for word, i in text_tokenizer.word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size,
                        100,
                        embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix),
                        input_length=50,
                        trainable=False)
```

With the architecture looking like this:

```
sequence_input = Input(shape=(50,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
text_cnn = Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=5, padding='same',     activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
text_lstm = LSTM(500, return_sequences=True)(embedded_sequences)


char_in = Input(shape=(50, 18, ))
char_cnn = Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu')(char_in)
char_cnn = GaussianNoise(0.40)(char_cnn)
char_lstm = LSTM(500, return_sequences=True)(char_in)



merged = concatenate([char_lstm, text_lstm]) 

merged_d1 = Dense(800, activation='relu')(merged)
merged_d1 = Dropout(0.5)(merged_d1)

text_class = Dense(len(y_unique), activation='softmax')(merged_d1)
model = Model([sequence_input,char_in], text_class)
```

When I go to convert the model to json, I get this error:

```
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Similarly, if I use the `model.save()` function, it seems to save correctly, but when I go to load it, I get `Type Error: Expected Float32`.

My question is: is there something I am missing when trying to serialize this model? Do I need some sort of `Lambda` layer or something of the sorts?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Additionally you should use model checkpoint to save model since `model.save()` does not save the best model iteration instead it simply save the last iteration which may not be the best iteration always. So save best weights and use `model.to_json()` to save model architecture. Find more details [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2768)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `weights` argument in `Embedding` layer to provide initial weights.

```py
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size,
                            100,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=50,
                            trainable=False)
```

The weights should remain non-trainable after model saving/loading:

```py
model.save('1.h5')
m = load_model('1.h5')
m.summary()

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)            (None, 50)           0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_4 (InputLayer)            (None, 50, 18)       0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)         (None, 50, 100)      1000000     input_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                   (None, 50, 500)      1038000     input_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                   (None, 50, 500)      1202000     embedding_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 50, 1000)     0           lstm_4[0][0]
                                                                 lstm_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 50, 800)      800800      concatenate_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 50, 800)      0           dense_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 50, 15)       12015       dropout_2[0][0]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 4,052,815
Trainable params: 3,052,815
Non-trainable params: 1,000,000
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are saving the model after compiling. Like:

```
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

To save model, you can do:

```
    from keras.models import load_model

    model.save('model.h5')
    model = load_model('model_detect1.h5')
    model_json = model.to_json()
    with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json)
```

To load model,

```
    from keras.models import model_from_json

    json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
    model_json = json_file.read()
    model = model_from_json(model_json)
    model.load_weights("model.h5")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple methods . The problem is when we work in the embedding layer, then pickle doesnt work, and is not able to save the data.
SO what you can do , when you have some layers like these:-

```
## Creating model
embedding_vector_features=100
model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(voc_size,embedding_vector_features,input_length=sent_length))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

then, u can use
h5 extension to d=save file, and then convert that to json, model converetd to model2 here

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model.save('model.h5')
model = load_model('model.h5')
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
json_file.write(model_json)
```

and this to load data:-

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
model_json = json_file.read()
model2 = model_from_json(model_json)
model2.load_weights("model.h5")
```